# How to create a 2MB array or vector and fill it with random integers

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, io

I want to create a static sized (2mb) container (in c++/visual studio 2008), probably an array or a vector and fill it with some random integers.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks.

I thought about doing smth like that:

```
int x[1048576];

for (int i=1; i<1048576; i++)
{
    int r = rand()%i;
    x[i] = r;
}
```

but making all in a for loop seemd a little bit weird I guess? That's why I asked even there is a standart procedure to do this job.

Comment: Do you have any specific problems with what you have tried already?

Comment: Do create it and assign it with random numbers cause problem with you? What you have tried?

Comment: sorry I forgat to put any code, I added now...

Comment: You are allocating a 4MB array on the stack (larger than the stack size - unless you increased that) and ignoring the x[0] and filling the rest. You did not seed the random number generator so you will get the same random numbers each time you run the program. That is except for x[0] and assuming you fixed the stack size so you do not have stack overflow.

Comment: I forgot to mention the increasing mod on your random numbers. Did you really want that?

Comment: also, some compilers have RAND_MAX = 32767, so using increasing mod like that wouldn't have meaning for large i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use something like:

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

...

// Create array
std::vector<int> arr(SIZE); 
// std::array<int, SIZE> arr; // for a static array;

// Seed randomness
std::srand(std::time(NULL));

// Randomize values
std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), &std::rand);
```

Use array like a normal array:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i != arr.size(); ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
```

And no need to `delete[]` or whatever because `vector` manages this for you.

Alternatively, you can create a "random" `iterator` which would yield random values. This would allow you to create & fill the vector at creation time, ending result would look like this: `std::vector<int> arr(rand_iterator(SIZE), rand_iterator());` but it's more work.

Comment: Yeah that kind of stuff I was looking for, thanks I'll try it right now

Comment: That'll generate 8MiB of random integers though insted of 2MB (2MiB?),  assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` (which is a kind of reasonable expectation). Yes I know I'm nitpicking, sorry... :-)

Comment: @Damon: good point :) I'll just replace all with SIZE in the examples because it's not the important part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int* array = new int[524288];
for (size_t k = 0; k < 524288; ++k)
    array[k] = rand();
```

and don't forget to delete the array afterwards.

Comment: This is a good start.  Don't forget to seed rand().  In some implementations rand() only returns a short.

Comment: -1: Why manual memory management? Why dynamic memory at all? If that is really required, could you at least include some notes on exception safety and the different new and delete operators, as well as a section on stack unwinding?

Comment: Why not? The (original) question looked like a very beginner's one, so my thought was that all these fancy things you mentioned were out of sope. And honestly, do you really expect `rand`to throw an exception, or what? The snippet was just a basic example. I don't see the need for a downvote.

Comment: Okay, honestly, as desired: `rand()` does not throw; `new` does. And all those "fancy" things, as you call them, are crucial for secure (non-backdoor) applications which you can all have for free when simply using a standard container. I think you underestimate the skill required for _correct_, manual memory management; using the right `delete` operator is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Nevertheless I think that for a beginner it's best to learn to deal with pointers, arrays and the like before advancing to the more - yes - *fancy* things. The phiolosophy you seem to adhere, i.e. to complete such things is at least questionable in my optinion. I'm not saying that your points are not worth being considered in for example security-related applications; there might indeed be cases where a 2MB allocation fails.. Still, the answer is not *wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 version (but not compatible with VS2008):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main() {
   const int mem = 2*1024*1024;
   const int cnt = mem/sizeof(int); // number of ints in 2MB :)

   std::vector<int> v(cnt);

   std::random_device rd;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis;

   std::generate( std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&]{ return dis(rd); } );

   return 0;
}
```